# PHP - Get width and height of a .ai file without iMagick

Tags: php, gd, imagick, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to get the width and height of a .ai image without Imagick ?
I searched with GD, but it seems to not work.

Thank you.

Comment: This may work: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: It says : To read meta data stored in the headers of the JPEG and TIFF images :/ 

Anyway I use TCPDF and I found that it can give me width and height of the image with getTemplateSize after import the image.

Thank for your help :D

Comment: yeah but its an .ai file. I'm sure there is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

With TCPDF I can get image's size with the getTemplateSize method after import the image.
I use TCPDF for generate a PDF and I need to insert images in it.

```
$this->pdf->setSourceFile($file);
$tmpl = $this->pdf->importPage(1);
$templateInfos = $this->pdf->getTemplateSize($tmpl);
```